# Generate two elements from one in Flux?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I'm having following `Flux`:

```
val myFlux = Flux.just("a", "b", "duck", "c", "d")
```

I would like to transform it in a way that each occurrence of `duck` will produce two elements (eg. `Leg`)

So:

```
myMyFlux.magicTransformation()
```

should produce:

```
"a", "b", "leg", "leg", "c", "d"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to map `duck` into two elements.

```
val myFlux = Flux.just("a", "b", "duck", "c", "d")

myFlux.flatMap {
    if (it == "duck") {
        Flux.just("leg", "leg")
    } else {
        Mono.just(it)
    }
}.subscribe(System.out::println)
```

Comment: I've found also `concatMapIterable` but `flatMap` is also nice